# Huawei switch mac address sticky (model S5720) persistence after power cycle

Tags: mac-address, switchport, huawei

Suppose I configure the commands "port-security enable,  port-security mac-address sticky" in a Huawei switch port, then an endpoint device is connected on the switch port, and a MAC address is learned (verified with the "display mac-address sticky" command).
Is this specific MAC address stickiness persistent **after disconnecting the device and then power cycling the switch**? If yes, does saving the switch configuration with the "save" command affect the way this stickiness works?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I found the answer (finally...) here:

> Manually configured and auto-generated sticky MAC address entries are
> automatically saved in a .ztbl or .ctbl file every 10 minutes.
> Alternatively, you can run the save command to manually save them. The
> saved file is not discarded after the device restarts. The file name
> must be the same as that of the system configuration file. For
> example, if the name of the system configuration file is test.cfg, the
> name of the sticky MAC address entry file must be test.ctbl.
> Otherwise, sticky MAC address entries will fail to be restored after
> the device restarts.

source: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/br/doc/EDOC1100116719/b27717f3/port-security-mac-address-sticky